# How to load image from database using jquery ajax in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am creating comment system in ASP.Net through jQuery AJAX but I am facing a problem of loading images from the database. I have 3 tables in the database:

1. UserRegistration(uid(PK),username....)
2. Profile(profileID(PK),uid(FK),fulname,userPic...)
3. Comment(cmntID(PK),cmntText,uid(FK)....)

The following is the jQuery AJAX code:

```
function getcomment() {
    var postPlace = $('div.q1');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/WebForm1.aspx/GetComment',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            var newData = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            var trHtml = '';
            var loadPost = postPlace;

            $.each(newData, function (i, item) {
                trHtml += '<div class="q2" style="background-color: red">' +
                   '<img src="' + item.userPic + '" class="img-circle" width="32px" height="32px" />'+
                   '<span>' + item.username + '</span>' +
                   '<p>' + item.cmntText + '</p>' + '</div>';
            });
            loadPost.html(trHtml);
        }
```

Here is the problem with `item.userPic` which is inside the loop. `item.username` and `item.cmntText` works well but `item.userPic` is not working. However when i access another attribute of the Profile table like `fulname` then it works. I just can't access `userPic` of the same table.

This is the code behind in C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetComment()
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from userregistration inner join comment on userregistration.uid=comment.uid inner join profile on comment.uid=profile.uid  order by cmntID DESC ", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}
```

This is the result that I get:

[image]

Comment: We need some more detail here. Is the userpic stored as a string path or a base64 encoded string? What is the value you get? What is the value you expect?

Comment: I think he become an json as response. So can you please check your console.logs and check the image path (open URL in new tab) to check availbilty.

Comment: @Rory he userPic is stored as a string path so i just want to display that stored images from database using jquery ajax

Comment: What does `console.log(item.userPic)` log at `console`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are retrieving a base64 encoded string, set the 'src' attribute of the image tag with the base64 encoded string.
For example:

```
$("#img").attr('src','data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
```

In case you are retrieving the path of the image, you have to retrieve the image using ajax call and use the    `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")` in asmx where you have to specify the location of your image folder.

add the below code snippet to a function or web method,

```
string strdocPath;
        try
        {
            strdocPath = (Server.MapPath("~\\Uploads\\" + DocumentName));

            FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int len = (int)objfilestream.Length;
            Byte[] documentcontents = new Byte[len];
            objfilestream.Read(documentcontents, 0, len);
            objfilestream.Close();
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(documentcontents);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
```

Note: Replace the 'Uploads' according to your needs which is the folder where your image exists. Also note that i'm passing the 'DocumentName' which is actually the file name only.

Comment: i'm using string path not base64.....
kindly explain it with an example if you don't mind plz i really need it ....

and i'm storing image like this:

fileupload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileupload.FileName);

Comment: This will make the whole request too slow and its size will be huge, specially if there were many comments

Answer (score 0):

You have to another page or handler that accepts user id and returns an image, the code should works as below:

In the JavaScript block, you will change the part that draws the image tag

```
$.each(newData, function (i, item) {
                trHtml += '<div class="q2" style="background-color: red">' +
                   '<img src="/GetUserImage?userId=' + item.username + '" class="img-circle" width="32px" height="32px" />'+
                   '<span>' + item.username + '</span>' +
                   '<p>' + item.cmntText + '</p>' + '</div>';
            });
```

Then create a new HTTP Handler as below

```
public class UserImagesHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Get username from from query string

        //Get binary data

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    }
}
```

Then register the handler in web.config