# this keyword not passing to another function in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey i'm gonna creating a real time comment system in asp.net using jquery ajax...

i have to functions insertComment() and getComment()...

the first problem was that 'this' wasn't working inside a function than i searched about it and i solved it by pass 'this' keywork as function argument like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Post" id="btnComment" onclick="insertComment(this);" />
```

so in short i have done insert Comment section but now i actually faced the same 'this' keyword problem i think bcz now when i call the getComment() function inside insertComment() than it fired pretty cool but there in getComment() function i also need 'this' keyword , i have tried but not working for me

Bellow is the full code:

**insertComment Method**

```
function insertComment(com) {

        var txtComment = $(com).parent('div.Comment-Post-2').parent('div.Comment-Post').parent('div.d8').children('div.Comment-Post').children('div.Comment-Post-2').children('.txtComment').val();

        $.ajax({

            url: 'index.aspx/NewComment',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: '{cmntText: "' + txtComment + '"}',
            success: function (com) {

//here i'm calling the getComment function and passing 'this' keyword but its not works inside the getComment funciton

                getcomment(this);



                $('.txtComment').val("");

            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

**getComment Method**

```
function getcomment(g) {

//this function calls when comment inserts and alerts ('works') pretty well  but the $(g).pa.... not working

        alert("works");
        $(g).parents('div.Comment-Section').hide();
}
```

Please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Which element are you trying to set as `this` at `success` callback?

Comment: sir, in the success  i'm just passing 'this' keyword to getComment function just like i have done on button click event

Comment: Yes, what is `this` expected to be within `success`? `#btnComment` element ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `context` option of `$.ajax()` to set `this` within `success` callback

```
  $.ajax({
    context: /* element or object which should be `this` at `success` */
  })
```

Comment: sorry sir i'm really new to jquery ajax ... i can't understand this ... so plz if you don't mind give example according to my need i mean .... i have a button for inserting a comment when i press that button than insertComment() function should be called and inside insertComment() ajax success call another function getComment() and when getComment() called than a div with class="Comment-Section" should be hide..
i have done it like this : $('div.Comment-Section').hide();

than its work but the problem is it hide all the Comment-Section divs of every Post so i just want to hide...

Comment: i just want to hide a specific one and i know it can be done by using 'this' keyword :
e.g: $(this).parents('div.Comment-Section').hide();

but 'this' keyword not works here so i want to pass 'this' keyword to getComment() when it is called in inertComment so plz i need ur help its a part of  my final year project which is socail networking site and just 5 days remmaining for submission but here i'm just stucked ....

Comment: @Heartlion Which element should be `this` when you want to hide a specific element? Can you include `html` at Question to indicate which element you are referring to? Are you trying to pass the clicked element `<input type="button" value="Post" id="btnComment" onclick="insertComment(this);" />
` as `this`?

Comment: oh my God i have solved it luckly .... i just passed the same 'com' parameter to getComment() instead passing 'this'....it works for me now... and thank u so much  @guest271314 for ur help :)

Comment: excuse me sir can you please take a look at my another jquery ajax question if you don't mind

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015045/how-to-load-image-from-database-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net/40015498#40015498

Comment: @Heartlion Note, there are two `com` variables at `javascript`; consider renaming one of them to avoid mistaking one for the other.

Comment: oops the in success:function(..mistakenly putted ;)..){}

Comment: can you please check out this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015045/how-to-load-image-from-database-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net/40015498#40015498

Answer (score 0):

In the line `getcomment(this);`, `this` is not referring to the object you want to refer to since it is inside another function. Define it before ajax and then you should be able to use it

```
function insertComment(com) {

  var txtComment = $(com).parent('div.Comment-Post-2').parent('div.Comment-Post').parent('div.d8').children('div.Comment-Post').children('div.Comment-Post-2').children('.txtComment').val();

  var obj = this ; /* or any thing you want */

    $.ajax({

        url: 'index.aspx/NewComment',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: '{cmntText: "' + txtComment + '"}',
        success: function (com) {

        //here i'm calling the getComment function and passing 'this' keyword but its not works inside the getComment funciton

            getcomment(obj);



            $('.txtComment').val("");

        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `this` when you already have the calling object in `com` ?? What are you trying to refer to ??

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it by passing 'com' parameter of insertComment as getComment argument:

```
function insertComment(com) {

    var txtComment = $(com).parent('div.Comment-Post-2').parent('div.Comment-Post').parent('div.d8').children('div.Comment-Post').children('div.Comment-Post-2').children('.txtComment').val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'index.aspx/NewComment',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: '{cmntText: "' + txtComment + '"}',
        success: function () {

//here i just passed 'com' instead 'this' and now it works

            getcomment(com);



            $('.txtComment').val("");

        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```